# Can't mount ZFS or change encryption key after raw receive

Tags: linux, zfs

To do a backup of my encrypted filesystem, I did `zfs send -w fs@snap | zfs receive fs2/root` (It was the only snapshot; I hadn't known better and created my source filesystem on the root level).

Now I can't seem to access the data on fs2/root. The `keylocation` property says `prompt` when really it should be `file:///...`. I tried to follow [this advice](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/6847) and do `zfs change-key -i fs2/root`.

However, this fails with the message `Key change error: Key must be loaded`. However, when I try to load the key for fs2/root, it fails with the message `Key load error: Cannot enter raw keys on the terminal`. I never specified any passphrase I could enter anyway.

Is there a way to solve the situation, ideally without copying the data again? I'm using zfs 0.8.3-1 on Devuan ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to explicitly set the key location to the key file with `zfs set keylocation=...`. Then the key could be loaded. Letting the filesystem inherit the encryption settings from the parent by doing `zfs change-key -i` then also worked. :)